# Google drive api authorization returns 404 not found error, after authorization accepted

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from Google import Create_Service
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
import google_auth_oauthlib
import pypandoc
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents=intents)

@bot.command()



async def gif(ctx):
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
    API_NAME = 'drive'
    API_VERSION = 'v3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    
    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

    file_id = '16f4MOIxs3yGS3oIXUIGbt3Tj6LLVYhxCMHl3XLFu4bY'

    byteData = service.files().export_media(
        fileId = file_id,
        mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
```

[image: this is the local host problem]

I wanted to make google API work with server but I can't figure out how to make google API allow transfer data to server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have create an installed application. the redirect uri you are using is that of localhost. Yet you do not have a web server running on your machine so its giving you a 404 when returning to you the authorization code.

The solution would be to do what they do in the [python quickstart for google drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python)

Here they use `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)` to spawn a local web server to accept the authorization code response from the authorization process.

## Code

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```